strace output, syscall parameters
I am a newbie on linux internals -
what does the different integer values after read syscall mean?
I've seen read(0, read(5, read(6, read(12 .
Are they file descriptors?
3342  read(6, "\n# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.\n# SELI"..., 4096) = 548
3342  read(6, "", 4096)                 = 0
3342  read(6, "privsep_preauth=sshd_net_t\n", 4096) = 27
3342  read(6, "", 4096)                 = 0
3342  read(6, "system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023\0", 4095) = 40
3342  read(4, "\0\0\5\344\n\248\\\371\240\212\20j\204,\272\253-\332\326\351\303\0\0\0\361curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@li"..., 8192) = 1512
3341  read(6, "\0\0\0a", 4)             = 4
3342  read(5,  <unfinished ...>
3341  read(6, "x\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\35chacha20-    poly1305@openssh.com\0\0\0\n<implicit>\0\0\0\4none\0\0\0\21"..., 97) = 97
3342  <... read resumed>"\0\0\0\1", 4)  = 4
3342  read(5, "y", 1)                   = 1


The first parameter is the file descriptor,  The third parameter is the size of the buffer.  The number at the end is the number of bytes that were actually read.  You can find open or creat calls prior to this to find out what files correspond to which file descriptors.

The strace utility does not have access to source code. It is forced to just display the numeric value (or the pointer contents such as a text string) of each argument passed in that instance of each syscall. If those runtime values were omitted, then the strace utility would have very limited usefulness.

Yes. The first argument to read() is the file descriptor. The best way to interpret strace calls it to man 2 the desired call. e.g.:
read(2)                           System Calls Manual                           read(2)
NAME
read - read from a file descriptor
LIBRARY
Standard C library (libc, -lc)
SYNOPSIS
#include <unistd.h>
   ssize_t read(int fd, void buf[.count], size_t count);

